# Custom file handler for SharePoint using azure AD enterprise application addin

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad, azure-ad-graph-api, azureadapps

I am trying to create a custom file handler add-in for SharePoint online just like 'Adobe Document Cloud',
I will be opening PDF type files in my own cloud viewer.

I followed the steps in

[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/?view=odsp-graph-online#:~:text=File%20Handlers%20are%20a%20type,experiences%20for%20any%20proprietary%20format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/?view=odsp-graph-online#:%7E:text=File%20Handlers%20are%20a%20type,experiences%20for%20any%20proprietary%20format).

1. Registered a new multitenant app in azure active directory
2. Modified the app-manifest and added value from above blog to addins section (all the URLs are dummy urls (not actual URls))
3. Provided graph API permission to read and write all files user have access to
4. However I cannot see the changes in my site collection, PDFs are still opened by default viewer and icon didn't changed (it should show image not found), I waited more than 24 hours still same behavior
5. Are there any more steps that I need to do?

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
"id": "941be707-3eb9-4b9c-8844-e949b1f8ff89",
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,
"addIns": [
    {
        "id": "328486ea-7159-4b6a-a2aa-f036b2423b23",
        "type": "FileHandler",
        "properties": [
            {
                "key": "version",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "key": "fileTypeDisplayName",
                "value": "Contoso Markdown"
            },
            {
                "key": "fileTypeIcon",
                "value": "{\"svg\":\"https://localhost:3000/images/icons/icon.svg\",\"png1x\":\"https://localhost:3000/images/icons/icon@1x.png\",\"png1.5x\":\"https://localhost:3000/images/icons/icon@1.5x.png\",\"png2x\":\"https://localhost:3000/images/icons/icon@2x.png\"}"
            },
            {
                "key": "appIcon",
                "value": "{\"svg\":\"https://localhost:3000/images/icons/app-icon.svg\",\"png1x\":\"https://localhost:3000/images/icons/app-icon@1x.png\",\"png1.5x\":\"https://localhost:3000/images/icons/app-icon@1.5x.png\",\"png2x\":\"https://localhost:3000/images/icons/app-icon@2x.png\"}"
            },
            {
                "key": "actions",
                "value": "[{\"type\":\"open\",\"url\":\"https://localhost:3000/markdown/edit\",\"availableOn\":{\"file\":{\"extensions\":[\".pdf\"]},\"web\":{}}}]"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"allowPublicClient": null,
"appId": "ff2e8ff5-d47e-4883-8ce5-262550003e99",
"appRoles": [],
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"createdDateTime": "2021-04-21T19:23:22Z",
"disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"identifierUris": [],
"informationalUrls": {
    "termsOfService": null,
    "support": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "marketing": null
},
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": "https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/dbd5a2dd-j19ryprcukldjv9rpgnkhsexivuvwxlgq6bcbtf4ip8/appbranding/xf3qxccqau-tnctzzm8i-rydriera0tb0el2bxgasuk/1033/bannerlogo?ts=637546298437565699",
"logoutUrl": "https://localhost:44321/signout-callback-oidc",
"name": "MuhimbiCustomFileHandler",
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2Permissions": [],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
},
"passwordCredentials": [],
"preAuthorizedApplications": [],
"publisherDomain": "M365x298713.onmicrosoft.com",
"replyUrlsWithType": [
    {
        "url": "https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc",
        "type": "Web"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://localhost:44321/",
        "type": "Web"
    }
],
"requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
        "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
        "resourceAccess": [
            {
                "id": "17dde5bd-8c17-420f-a486-969730c1b827",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "863451e7-0667-486c-a5d6-d135439485f0",
                "type": "Scope"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInUrl": null,
"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",
"tags": [],
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
```

}